# Bash script is returning "gh: Not Found (HTTP 404) Error: writing output failed: Invalid argument" when trying multiple actions on GitHub repos

Tags: bash, api, github

I'm trying to rename a large number of branches at once, and account for three possible scenarios, using the following in Bash:

```
for REPOSITORY in "${REPOSITORIES[@]}"; do
     
    # no master or main 
    if [ "$(gh api repos/${REPOSITORYOWNER}/${REPOSITORY}/branches/master | jq -r .message)" = "Branch not found" ] || [ "$(gh api /repos/${REPOSITORYOWNER}/${REPOSITORY}/branches/main | jq -r .message)" = "Branch not found" ]; then
        echo "branch doesn't exist"
        git branch main

    # master exists, rename it
    elif [ "$(gh api repos/${REPOSITORYOWNER}/${REPOSITORY}/branches/master | jq -r .message)" = "200" ]; then
            echo "Renaming master to main on ${REPOSITORY}"
            gh api \
                --method POST \
                -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
                repos/${REPOSITORYOWNER}/${REPOSITORY}/branches/master/rename \
                -f new_name='main'

    # main exists, do nothing
    elif [ "$(gh api repos/${REPOSITORYOWNER}/${REPOSITORY}/branches/main | jq -r .message)" = "200" ]; then
        echo "main branch already exists"
        :
    fi
done
```

However all I'm getting back is `gh: Not Found (HTTP 404) Error: writing output failed: Invalid argument`. The gh api calls are correct so I'm assuming this is a syntax error but I'm pretty new to Bash.

```
gh api \
                --method POST \
                -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
                repos/${REPOSITORYOWNER}/${REPOSITORY}/branches/master/rename \
                -f new_name='main'
```

Works by itself, but none of the if statements work individually. I am expecting it to run through each possible state and move onto the next if statement if the conditions aren't met.

EDIT: I added `set -x` and it looks like it is returning a lot of null messages, see below:

```
 for REPOSITORY in "${REPOSITORIES[@]}"
++ gh api repos/owner/repo/branches/master
++ jq -r .message
+ '[' null = 'Branch not found' ']'
++ gh api /repos/owner/repo/branches/main
++ jq -r .message
gh: Not Found (HTTP 404)
+ '[' 'Not Found' = 'Branch not found' ']'
++ gh api repos/owner/repo/branches/master
++ jq -r .message
+ '[' null = 200 ']'
++ gh api repos/owner/repo/branches/main
++ jq -r .message
+ '[' null = 200 ']'
```

Comment: Add the `set -x` command at the beginning to turn on bash execution tracing, and see what's actually happening as it runs. My guess would be that some of your variable don't hold exactly the values you expect, but without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I can only speculate.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have repeating expressions.  Outputs to those should be assigned to variables that make it easier to follow the logic of the program.

Also, you had more paths without the leading "**/**", so I removed that from the determination for **stat_main**, but shouldn't they ALL have the leading "**/**" ???   (N.B.  I don't upload to github, so no experience with what is expected by that command.)

OR ... use a proper fullpath definition (rather than relative to the current, possibly unknown or mis-fit, location ?

**More importantly**, until your logic behaves the way you want, **you need to comment out the rename action** and replace it with an **echo "rename action"**, to avoid applying that to something that should **NOT** be renamed.

Here is my modification of that code segment:

```
for REPOSITORY in "${REPOSITORIES[@]}"; do

    repo_path="repos/${REPOSITORYOWNER}/${REPOSITORY}/branches"

    stat_master="$(gh api ${repo_path}/master | jq -r .message)"
    echo "\t stat_master = ${stat_master}"

    stat_main="$(gh api ${repo_path}/main | jq -r .message)"
    echo "\t stat_main = ${stat_main}"

    # no master or main
    if [ "${stat_master}" = "Branch not found" -o " ${stat_main}" = "Branch not found" ]
    then
        echo "branch doesn't exist"
        git branch main

    # master exists, rename it
    elif [ "${stat_master}" = "200" ]
    then
            echo "Renaming master to main on ${REPOSITORY}"
            gh api \
                --method POST \
                -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
                ${repo_path}/master/rename \
                -f new_name='main'

    # main exists, do nothing
    elif [ "${stat_main}" = "200" ]
    then
        echo "main branch already exists"
        :
    fi
done
```